# Calculating the percentage of amino acid composition for each column in csv

Tags: python, csv, percentage

sample file:

```
Column header 95: A|T|E|A|A|Y|E|A|E|A
Column header 96: W|I|Q|Q|A|L|P|K|E|A
Column header 97: S|D|F|Q|G|Y|E|A|E|A
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of amino acid composition for each column from csv file.
I'm able to calculate only for first column, but unable to iterate over the remaining columns and print the percentage for all columns.

```
import csv
with open ('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    column = [row[0] for row in reader]
    amino_acids = {}
    for aa in column:
        if aa in amino_acids:
            amino_acids[aa] += 1
        else:
            amino_acids[aa] = 1
    for aa, count in amino_acids.items():
        #print(f'{aa}: {count}')
        percentage = count / len (column) *100
        print (f"{aa}: {percentage: .2f}%")
```

Expected output:

```
column header 95:
A=50%
E=30% and so on
similarly for the remaining columns.
```

Please suggest

Comment: This is not a CSV file

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what way your input is, but you can apply following code on each row,

Code:

```
s = 'A|T|E|A|A|Y|E|A|E|A'.split('|')
['{}={}%'.format(i, ls.count(i)/len(ls)*100) for i in set(ls)]
```

Output:

```
['T=10.0%', 'A=50.0%', 'E=30.0%', 'Y=10.0%']
```

Answer (score 1):

Process use basic Python file read since not a CSV file

**Code**

```
from collections import Counter

def show_stats(filename):
    ' shows the percentage of amino acids for each line in file '
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip().split(':')         # remove trailing '\n' and split on ':'
            column_info, sequence = line            # separate into colum info and amino acid sequence
            sequence = sequence.strip().split('|')  # remove leading & trailing whitesplace and split on '|'
            amino_acids = Counter(sequence)         # Count of each amino acid in sequence
            percent_convert_factor = 100.0/sum(amino_acids.values())    # 100 divided by total count (for conversion to percent)
            for k in amino_acids:
                amino_acids[k] *= percent_convert_factor                # convert counts to percentage
            amino_acids = dict(sorted(amino_acids.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[0]))   # in ascending order by amino acid
            print(column_info)                                                        # Column header
            print('\n'.join(f"{aa}={percentage: .2f}%" for aa, count in amino_acids.items())) # Amino acid percentages
        
# Process file    
show_stats('test.csv')
```

**Output**

```
Column header 95
A= 50.00%
E= 30.00%
T= 10.00%
Y= 10.00%
Column header 96
A= 20.00%
E= 10.00%
I= 10.00%
K= 10.00%
L= 10.00%
P= 10.00%
Q= 20.00%
W= 10.00%
Column header 97
A= 20.00%
D= 10.00%
E= 20.00%
F= 10.00%
G= 10.00%
Q= 10.00%
S= 10.00%
Y= 10.00%
```

​

Comment: Thank you for the solution, the sample file is just for representative purpose, mine i s.csv fie with around 1 million columns.  I've tried with my file but its got the following error "ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 4
      2 for line in f:
      3     line = line.rstrip().split(':')         
----> 4     column_info, sequence = line            
      5     sequence = sequence.strip().split('|') 
      6     amino_acids = {}                        

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
"

Comment: @user20578273 do some data lines not follow the format you showed i.e. column information followed by a ":" followed by amino acids?

Comment: @user20578273 if each line has a million amino acids I could find a faster way to count amino acids (i.e. with Python loop).  However, first I need to know the format is correct (thus the question in my previous comment on format).

Comment: @user20578273 modified code to use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to speed counting of  amino acids.